# @OneToOne associations cannot be eagerly loaded in query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I have the following entities:

```
//The class Entity is a @MappedSuperclass with id, audit fields, equals and so on.
@Entity
public class Foo extends Entity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<Bar>; // + getter/setter

    // ... other properties
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends Entity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo; // +getter/setter

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "baz_id", nullable = false)
    private Baz baz; // + getter/setter

    // ... other properties
}

@Entity
public class Baz extends Entity {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "baz", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Bar bar; // + getter/setter

    // ... other properties
}
```

Now if I load a `Bar` with the following, all is well (i.e. only one query is sent to the DB):

```
SELECT bar FROM Bar bar LEFT JOIN FETCH bar.baz WHERE bar.id = :barId
```

However, If I do either of the following, a new `SELECT` is created for every `Baz` to get the associated `Bar` object:

```
SELECT f FROM Foo f LEFT JOIN FETCH f.bars bar LEFT JOIN FETCH bar.baz WHERE f.id = :fooId
SELECT f FROM Foo f LEFT JOIN FETCH f.bars bar LEFT JOIN FETCH bar.baz baz LEFT JOIN FETCH baz.bar WHERE f.id = :fooId
```

The output is:

```
10:52:08,622 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select ... from Foo ...
10:52:08,698 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select ... from Bar where baz_id=?
10:52:08,711 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select ... from Bar where baz_id=?
... and so on
```

Now, I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445694/224143) that `@OneToOne` has problems with lazy loading, so I followed their advice and added optional = false (which didn't seem to do much for me).

I also tried suggestion 3 from [this blogpost](http://justonjava.blogspot.dk/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html), but that seems to have no effect at all..

Any suggestions how to eagerly fetch the object graph to avoid the SELECT n+1 issue?

I use EJB 3 (JPA 1) with Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1 on a JBoss 4.2 server.

NOTE: This is somewhat analogous to one of my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378656/avoiding-n1-eager-fetching-of-child-collection-element-association). The difference is that here `Baz` has a reference back to `Bar` which seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue, by removing the back reference from Baz to Bar. I did not find the underlying cause, or a way to load the objects eagerly without the extra selects.